# Render multiple images in R shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

is there any way in R, shinydashboard, to render multiple images in the dashboard body based on the `selectinput` option?

Here are my codes:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

images_a <- list.files("input/plots 1/", pattern = ".png") # 6 'png' images are in the *input/plots 1* folder
images_b <- list.files("input/plots 1/", pattern = ".jpg") # 5 'jpg' images are in the *input/plots 1* folder

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(selectInput(inputId = "image_type", label = "Image type", choices = c("png", "jpg"), selected = "png")),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `lapply( )` to loop through in `renderImage( )`

```
download.file("http://dehayf5mhw1h7.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/38/2016/01/18220900/Getty_011816_Bluepenguin.jpg",
                  destfile = "Bowie.png")
    download.file("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_cBH6cWZr1IU/TUURNp7LADI/AAAAAAAABsY/76UhGhmxjzY/s640/penguin+cookies_0018.jpg",
                  destfile = "Cookie.png")
    
    function(input, output) {
    
      output$img1 <- renderImage({   #This is where the image is set 
        if(input$var == "Bowie"){            
          list(src = "Bowie.png", height = 240, width = 300)
        }                                        
        else if(input$var == "Cookie"){
          list(src = "Cookie.png", height = 240, width = 300)
        }
        else if(input$var == "Renesme"){
          list(src = "Renesme.png", height = 240, width = 300)
        }
        else if(input$var == "Mango"){
          list(src = "Mango.png", height = 240, width = 300)
        }
      })
```

Comment: Thank you Ujjawal Bhandari, do you know how to loop through the *renderImage*?

Comment: Attached two pictures below.